# firebase deploy error, what's wrong with the following code?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

this is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nextServer"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source":       "**/build/**"    ,
    "runtime": "nodejs12"
  }
}
```

this is function.js

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: '.next' },
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    return server.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res)
        });
});
```

here I added in package.json

```
{
  "name": "jiva",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "function.js",
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Your source path does not resolve to a relative path.